# Symfony PHP - date widget format and database date field

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have a form where I have widget like this:

```
  $this->widgetSchema['valid_to'] 
          = new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format'=>'%day%/%month%/%year%','years'=>range('1990',date('Y')+5)), array());
```

Unfortunately the date format also caused that it tries to save date with that format into database which of course is bad.

Can anyone tell how to repair this?

Thanks in advance
Gabe

Comment: Can you post the error message that you got?

Comment: There is no error, when I pick for example 31/12/2011 I get 0031-12-31 or something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this solution, settings and code, in my backend that you can easily fit to your project.

In `apps/backend/config/settings.yml`:

```
 all:
  .settings:
    default_culture: it_IT
    i18n:            on
```

In `apps/backend/i18n/messages.it.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
  <file original="global" source-language="it" datatype="plaintext">
    <body>
      <trans-unit id="1">
        <source>Hello</source>
        <target>Ciao</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="2">
        <source><![CDATA[%month% %day% %year%]]></source>
        <target><![CDATA[%day% %month% %year%]]></target>
      </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

In date widget this `format`:

```
'format' => sfContext::getInstance()->getI18N()->__('%month% %day% %year%')
```

The date will be saved in the format yyyy-mm-dd but displayed in the culture you setted up.

Comment: Thx for the tip, sorry for late reply. I had to create the messages.pl.xml the I have pasted the <trans-unit... part. But I do not know what is the whole structure of messages*.xml. After my changes it still is something wrong

Comment: I have been updated the post by placing the structure of the file messages.it.xml. What errors do you have after your changes? (Remeber to clear the cache after each change to this file, also if you are using frontend_dev.php/backend_dev.php)